# Is there a tag wiki edit limit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I recently started to edit tag wiki's and after I edited some of them (still waiting on peer review) I cannot edit any other.

What is the limit of wiki edits a user can have at a certain time waiting on approval?

Comment: You can have at most 5 pending suggested edits. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit. Specifically, [you are limited to 5 *pending* suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202). Once those edits are approved by other community members, you will be able to suggest additional edits.

For tag wikis, you will not gain full edit privileges (the ability to make edits directly, without them passing through the "suggested edits" queue) until you reach [20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Just for clarity, the same limits apply to editing questions and answers, too. It's just that you have over 2k reputation, which means you have [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and your edits don't have to pass through the "suggested edits" queue. Thus, the "pending" limit no longer applies to you there.